# About Jquery events and DOM Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing some code on a wordpress site with woocommerce and if I execute jquery using `DOMContentLoaded` `load` `ready`, i've tried many, something is happening after my code that ruins up everything. If I run the script on console after everything is rendered it works. For now I made a simple interval with clearinterval a couple of seconds after and this way I manage my script to run at the final end of all code but I don't like this solution, the thing is that I need to learn more about this thing, whatever it is. I belive must be something related with DOM Tree Events? Really lost in space here...
Maybe using `setTimeout`? Haven't tried this one

Can you please show me where I can learn about this thing in specific, and please, if you can, avoid jquery.com and mozilla docs since I am such a beginner it's hard to understand them at my stage. I do understand better w3school because they have more examples so I can understand things. Thanks for the tip and getting me in the good direction.

Comment: You want to learn about jquery events but don't want to read jquery's website?

Comment: I said it's hard to understand for me at my stage, not that I don't want to. They don't use examples so good as W3 so that's why

Comment: The [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com) is about as good as it gets. If you don't like their examples, attempt making some of your own to get a better understanding - learn by doing, etc. One thing to note is that the W3chools site should not be used at all. It's notoriously bad for being out of date, or giving just plain wrong information. This is especially bad for beginners who don't have the skillset to evaluate the issues with their articles.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the tip. I value a lot the help. Can you please tell me exactly where should I start to learn concerning about my problem in the jquery website?